# Single package multiple namespace in struts2

Tags: java, struts2

Is it possible to have multiple namespace for a particular package in Struts2? Sorry if it  doesn't make any sense. Suppose if i have an action say

```
<package name="default" namespace="/abc" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="SayWelcome">
        <result>pages/welcome.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

I would like to have this action called for multiple namespaces like `/xyz`,`/efg` etc.Rather than replicating the package,is there some other way by which i could group it together.Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need multiple namespaces?

Comment: I have a namespace that contains quite a lot of actions.I need a new namespace that has almost the same functions as the current one.

Comment: Give namespace to the module that operate on some content, other modules that have different content should operate in another namespace. Separate code by grouping actions by the packages used by the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Struts2 packages](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/package-configuration.html) can inherit package behavior of the package it extends.

Use `extends` attribute of the `package` to define parent package.

```
<package name="your-default" namespace="/abc" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="SayWelcome">
        <result>pages/welcome.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>

<package name="xyz" namespace="/xyz" extends="your-default">

</package>
```

It is also possible to inherit from more than one package (`extends="default, other-default"`).